# How to find source code of `int()` function in python?

Tags: python, cpython

The code I tried to understand is:

```py
foo = int("123", 8)
print(foo)
```

I want to view the source code of builtin functions in python to see how int() is implemented. As I have tried, `sorted()` is located [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d246a6766b9d8cc625112906299c4cb019944300/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2237). Its function name is `builtin_sorted`, but nothing returns when I search `builtin_int` in the GitHub page.

Hope someone could help me understand its source code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: not the source code, but `int??` in the python console will give you some info. at least in ipython

Comment: You get there by searching `cpython int source code` on Google.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I find longobject.c. Thank you!

Comment: The "int" name in the "builtin" module is defined here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Python/bltinmodule.c#L3034. From there you can trace the definitions.